# Remove event references from Object for Garbage Collection to work

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

We have an issue where our application keeps on eating up RAM so I slapped some Diagnostic Tools on it and viewed three different snapshots of the process memory and noticed that each time we search for a user, the object (a form) created, is not being disposed on the forms `Close()`.

This is the code which happens when a user is searched.

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmCombinedSearch frmCmbSearch = new frmCombinedSearch();
    try
    {
        // Shows the 'form' in the same tab. This is a tabbed control.
        frmCmbSearch.ShowInTab(this.ParentTabPage);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.ShowException(ex);
    }
}
```

Once `frmCombinedSearch` is shown, the object lives on until another button is hit which eventually fires the `this.Close()` event on the form. From my understanding, the object is marked to be free'd up by the GC after this point.

After looking into the objects being created in the Diagnostic Tools session, I noticed that the object has `Event Handlers` that aren't unsubscribed from.

Below is the snippet from the Diagnostic tools which shows the additional objects being created after **four** person searches.

[image: Summary]

[image: Events]

How can I unsubscribe from the events manually so that the GC can free up the resources?

Comment: looks like you have issues because you are never disposing of the object instances correctly. try wrapping what you need around a `using` construct

Comment: As mentioned by @MethodMan you're never disposing the object (deleting all references to it) correctly. BTW why do you need always a new Object of the Form? Can't you just re-use the object till the parentForm is closed?

Comment: @MethodMan I can't use a `using` because `ShowInTab` is non-blocking, so I will be disposing of the object while it is still alive in the tabbed control.

Comment: Nope. The object will be eligible for garbage collection if there is no reference existing to it, but as you referencing it from your tabbed control the instance will probably never be eligible or you dispose it in/delete it from your tabbed control after it finished it job